# How to split this string to obtain just the name value

Tags: c#, string, split

Hi I am looking for a simple way to et just the name after the CN value

```
CN=Andrew Adams,OU=Services,OU=Users,OU=GIE,OU=CSP,OU=STAFF,DC=example,DC=net
```

is there an easy way to do this? I am currently doing this:

```
ResultPropertyValueCollection manager = result.Properties["manager"];
string managerUserName = manager[0].ToString();

string[] managerNameParts = managerUserName.Split(',');

string managerName = managerNameParts[0].Substring(4);

Console.WriteLine("Manager Name:" + managerName);
```

but it feels kind of bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great place to use Regular Expressions.  Try this:

```
var text = "CN=Andrew Adams,OU=Services,OU=Users,OU=GIE,OU=CSP,OU=STAFF,DC=example,DC=net";
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"CN=([^,]+)");
if (match.Success) return match.Groups[0].Value;
```

The expression `CN=([^,]+)` will look for the text `CN=` followed by one or more non-commas, and will stick that part of it into `Groups[0]`.

Comment: I like that this does not presume the order of the elements in the string.

Comment: I like this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var name = "CN=Andrew Adams,OU=Services,OU=Users,OU=GIE,OU=CSP,OU=STAFF,DC=example,DC=net"
.Split(',')[0].Split('=')[1];
```

[**Demo**](http://dotnetfiddle.net/AWqrFZ)

What it does is splits on `,` and takes the first element and then splits it by `=` and takes the second element.

If you cannot have the same format, you can do a regex:

```
Regex.Match(name,@"(?<=CN=)[^,]+").Value;
```

Comment: This could be smarter about finding the right element by looping through the first split's results and identifying the right element.  What if "CN" is not first?

Comment: This is what I would do if I knew the string was always going to be in the same format.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, using LINQ.

If the name/value pair exists anywhere in the string, you'll get it; if not, `managerName` will be `null`.

```
var managerName = input.Split(',')
                       .Where(x => x.StartsWith("CN="))
                       .Select(x => x.Split('=')[1])
                       .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I find doing it like this fairly easy to read:

```
var input = @"CN=Andrew Adams,OU=Services,OU=Users,OU=GIE,OU=CSP,OU=STAFF,DC=example,DC=net";

var items = input.Split(',');

var keyValues = items.Select(x =>
                {
                    var split = x.Split('=');
                    return new { Key = split[0], Value = split[1] };
                });

var managerName = keyValues.Single(x => x.Key == "CN").Value;
```